# Can not able create dashboard influxdb latest and above for grafana latest for jmetr data getting nulldata

Tags: jmeter, grafana, flux

Can not able use influxdb latest and above for grafana latest from download dashboard

I am using below dashboard
apache-jmeter-dashboard-by-ubikloadpack_rev1

I am getting everything as null
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Do7M.png)

I need latest grafana dashboard with support flux for jmeter data

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide a comprehensive answer without seeing the Grafana failure message (click exclamation sign) and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (preferably with [debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener))

Take a look at

- [JMeter InfluxDB v2.0 listener plugin](https://github.com/mderevyankoaqa/jmeter-influxdb2-listener-plugin)
- and [JMeter Load Test (org.md.jmeter.influxdb2.visualizer) - influxdb v2.0 (Flux)](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13644) dashboard

If "latest" is not a must you can take a look at